# python win32com.client outlook application is not filtering received emails

Tags: python, outlook, win32com, outlook-api

I wrote the code as below, but it doesn't do a time filter. what am i doing wrong?

```
import win32com.client
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

# setup range for outlook to search emails (so we don't go through the entire inbox)
    
received_dt = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
received_dt = received_dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')

# Select main Inbox
inbox = outlook.Folders("example@mydomain.com").Folders("Inboxx")
messages = inbox.Items.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + received_dt + "'")


for message in messages:
    print(str(message.ReceivedTime))
```

I am pasting the output of the code below.

```
2021-07-05 19:56:03.826000+00:00
2021-09-21 23:13:31.429000+00:00
2021-09-26 22:15:13.527000+00:00
2021-10-03 12:45:04.919000+00:00
2021-10-03 19:43:05.916000+00:00
2021-10-03 20:40:05.875000+00:00
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Maybe you should do the `inbox.Items.Restrict()` call *after* computing the restriction date. As your code stands, in a fresh session that call should give you an undefined local variable error. You are apparently not getting that error, so the variable must be lying around from a previous version of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to compute the date and time string before you call the Restrict method:

```
import win32com.client
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

# setup range for outlook to search emails (so we don't go through the entire inbox)
lastWeekDateTime = dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days= 7)
lastWeekDateTime = lastWeekDateTime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')  #<-- This format compatible with "Restrict"

received_dt = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
received_dt = received_dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')

# Select main Inbox
inbox = outlook.Folders("example@mydomain.com").Folders("Inboxx")
messages = inbox.Items.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + received_dt + "'")

for message in messages:
    print(str(message.ReceivedTime))
```

Read more about the `Restrict` method in the [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/) article.

Comment: you're right, it's my fault. I'm refactoring the code. The output of the code is still the same :(